# detect if a class is clicked using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 $(".Personalized").click(function(){

    $.ajax({

        type:"POST",
        url:"personalized.php",
        cache:false,
        beforeSend: function(){
            $('#loading_personalized').show();
            $('#triangle-personalized').show();
        },

        complete: function(){
            $('#loading_personalized').hide();

        },
        success: function(html){


            $("#divPersonalized").html(html).show();
        }

    });

});
```

when i click on personalized class the divPersoanlized shows up,,now i want to hide it on again clicking on personalized..how can i do it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally you'd just use `toggle()` to toggle the element, but in this case you probably don't want to run the ajax call every time

```
$(".Personalized").click(function(){

    if ( $("#divPersonalized").is(':visible') ) {

        $("#divPersonalized").hide();

    } else {

        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"personalized.php",
            cache:false,
            beforeSend: function(){
                $('#loading_personalized').show();
                $('#triangle-personalized').show();
            },
            complete: function(){
                $('#loading_personalized').hide();
            },
            success: function(html){
                $("#divPersonalized").html(html).show();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: "Normally you'd just use toggle() to toggle the element, but in this case you probably don't want to run the ajax call every time"... So what is the difference between your code and using toggle?

Comment: Using toggle you would just toggle the elements visibility, as that's what toggle does, but the way it's done above it doesn't just toggle the elements visibility, it also only runs the ajax call when the element is visible, not when it's hidden, as that wouldn't really make sense.

Answer (score 2):

For example like this:

```
$(".Personalized").click(function () {

    var $divPersonalized = $("#divPersonalized");

    if ($divPersonalized.is(':hidden')) {
        $.ajax({
            // ...
            success: function (html) {
                // Show the div
                $("#divPersonalized").html(html).show();
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        // Hide the div
        $divPersonalized.hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if div is visible just hide it. You don't need to call the ajax

```
$(".Personalized").click(function(){
    //You can use also use $(this).is(':visible')
    if($(this).css('display') !== "none"){
        $(this).hide();
        return;
    }

    //Your ajax code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To use the **visible** selector in jquery.  [visible doc.](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)

You can try this:

```
$(".Personalized").click(function(){


            if($('#divPersonalized').is(':visible')) {

                    $('#divPersonalized').hide();

            } else {

                 $.ajax({  

                      ...
                      ...
                        success: function(html){
                          $("#divPersonalized").html(html).show();
                        }
                      ...
                      ...
                 });
            }

});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use toggle method:

```
 $(".Personalized").toggle(ShowFunction, HideFunction);

    function ShowFunction(){
     // your code goes here
     $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"personalized.php",
            cache:false,
            beforeSend: function(){
                $('#loading_personalized').show();
                $('#triangle-personalized').show();
            },
            complete: function(){
                $('#loading_personalized').hide();
            },
            success: function(html){
                $("#divPersonalized").html(html).show();
            }
        });
    }

    function HideFunction(){
     // your code goes here.
      $("#divPersonalized").hide();
    }
```

Comment: Deprecated and removed from jQuery !

Comment: Which version of jQuery deprecated it?

Comment: [Deprecated in jQuery 1.8 and removed in 1.9](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/blob/master/warnings.md#jqmigrate-jqueryfntogglehandler-handler-is-deprecated)

Answer (score -1):

Use this:

```
if($("#divPersonalized").attr("hidden")=="hidden")
{
    $("#divPersonalized").removeAttr("hidden");
}
else
{
    $("#divPersonalized").attr("hidden","hidden");
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bExSy/1/)

**Update**

I updated the Demo.

Answer (score -1):

Throwing into the mix,  example of **separating the concerns** ( subjective ) -  worth a look.

```
(function() { /* wrap it to protect globals - optional */

   /* 1) set some variables accessible to all functions, eg */

    var contentdiv = $("#divPersonalized"), /* cache reused static selector(s) */
    hasdataloaded = false;

    /* 2) create a function to handle the data requests */

    function loaddata() {

        $.ajax({
            type:"POST", url:"personalized.php", cache:false,
            beforeSend: function(){
                $('#loading_personalized').show();
                $('#triangle-personalized').show();
            },
            complete: function(){
                $('#loading_personalized').hide();
            },
            success: function(html){
                hasdataloaded = true; /* updated the status */
                contentdiv.html(html);
            }
        });
    }

   /* 3) A function to handle the show and hide and checki if data has loaded */
       function toggleDataDiv() {
          contentdiv.toggle(); /* showhide */
          if(!hasdataloaded) {  loadData(); } /* only want to load once */
       } 

    /* 4) the event handler */
    $(".Personalized").click(function(){ toggleDataDiv();  });

   /* attach more events to other elements eg */
    $(".someotherelement").click(function() { toggleDataDiv();  });


})();
```